# растягивание предмета до других предметов Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть вертикальный скроллбар от TK2D в Unity. Он должен доставать своим нижним краем до нижней кнопки, верхним - до верхней. При изменении разрешения должен подстраиваться автоматически.

Если нужно просто таскать объект за другим объектом, работает вот это

Объект за которым таскаем - topAnchor,

Объект который таскаем - bar

```
 void Start()
{
    Align();
}

void Align()
{
    bar.transform.position = new Vector3(bar.transform.position.x, topAnchor.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.min.y, bar.transform.position.z);

}
void LateUpdate()
{
    if ((int)Tk2dGuiCamera.ScreenExtents.yMin != lastCamHeight)
    {
        lastCamHeight = Tk2dGuiCamera.ScreenExtents.yMin;
        Align();
    }
}
```

Но в данном случае задача несколько отличается, надо не таскать объект за другим, а растянуть его между двумя другими. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Эта задача не должна фиксится кодом.

Эта задача должна решатся правильными анкорами на канвасе.

Чтобы при изменении разрешения не было проблем — выставь канвас в соответствующий твоим потребностям режим скейла.

Не забудь повысить дефолтное разрешение канваса в два раза.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский
Там нет канваса. Это 2dToolkit.

Comment: @Dmitrii а я тут причем?

Comment: @Andrew 
Там нет канваса. Это 2DToolkit
По возможности хотелось бы решить проблему кодом

Comment: Тогда задача сугубо математическая. Выставь анкор у тулкита на нижнюю грань(ну  иль на верхнюю, не важно).   Просчитывай сколько от одной кнопки к другой. Потом скейль по вертикали твой скролл отталкиваясь от оригинальной высоты и той которую ты получил только что. Хотя это излишнее извращение, как по мне.